# JavaCC doesn't detect token

Tags: javacc

I have this token to detect a invalid invoice:

```
TOKEN : {
    < #invalid : <number><client>(<mail> | <mailCom>)<wrongDoc><text><retorn> > 
}
```

And this is my while loop:

```
while (ok) {

    token = app.getNextToken();
    switch (token.kind) {
        case TextoConstants.client:
            System.out.println(token.image);
            break;
        case TextoConstants.mailCom:
            System.out.println(token.image);
            break;
        case TextoConstants.text:
            System.out.println(token.image);
            break;
        case TextoConstants.invalid:
            System.out.println("There is something wrong");
            break;
    ok = token.kind != TextoConstants.EOF;
}
```

The problem is when I try to analyze some text block it prints the `client`/(`mailCom`)?/`text` tokens, but no the `invalid` one.

This is the input:

```
Number 30003
Client MyName,Lastname
Mail myname@mail.com
DocId 346774
Text
some text block here.
END
```

The output should be **There is something wrong**, but instead it prints the other tokens.

Thanks.

Comment: It looks to me like you are trying to do things with the lexer that would be better done by the parser.

Answer (score 1):

Since `#invalid` starts with a `#`, it is not a real token kind.  It's really just a macro that can be used to define other tokens.